# Match JSON POST data with custom node fields

Tags: 7, entities, services

Is there a fool-proof method to generate a correctly formatted JSON data object to be received by a create node resource given by a REST server, defined with [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) in Drupal 7?

I have setup a REST server accepting the `application/json` content type. I have also set up an anonymous endpoint with the `create node` resource enabled and I managed to create a new item with the Poster plugin for Firefox with Content Type set to `application/json` and the following data

```
{"title":"Review","type":"story"}
```

I can't seem to get any further though. I am following [this guide](http://drupal.org/node/1354202) and the node is created but my data for the rest of the fields is not added. I use this [JSON editor](http://braincast.nl/samples/jsoneditor/) to generate my code so it matches the structure shown by the `dsm($_POST)` call I placed in `node.module`'s `node_submit` handler for testing.

[image: data structure shown by dsm($_POST)]

The JSON data I am trying to post looks like this (I remove all whitespace before using Poster):

```
{
"title":"great success!",
"type":"story",
"field_review":[
    {"und":
        [{"0":
            [
                {"value":"Some text"}
            ]
        }]
    }
],
"field_rating":[
    {"und":
        [
            {"rating":"60"}
        ]
    }
],
"field_product_type":[
    {"und": "1"}
],
"field_barcode":[
    {"und":
        [
            {"value":"33333333333"}
        ]
    }
]
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function json_encode(); from my understanding.

Comment: Could you say a bit more? The function you refer to is a PHP function, if I understand it correctly, and I am trying to send data from an Android app (Java) to a Drupal REST server.

Comment: drupal_json_encode() turned out to be helpful, actually. See this thread: http://drupal.org/node/1354202#comment-6456602

Comment: if the suggestion was helpful than select my answer and vote it up :)

Comment: hi @benjamin_dk it would be really helpful if you could post some examples of how your json ended up looked for different field types. I'll follow the json_encode method at the link, but future visitors will really benefit. cheers