# how to implement a data receiver service in Drupal

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I have a Drupal site which will host a flash application. The application will be inserted in a node body (or as an attachment, not sure yet). I would like this application to send some data to Drupal (e.g. a game progress and score) using Javascript.

What I achieved so far is the ability to have the game score displayed in a Javascript alert  window in Json format. Next step would be to send it to Drupal and I want to save it to a table. I don't know how to do the "**Send it to Drupal**" part. What is the right way to do it, so it's hacker-proof etc?

Comment: Did you consider not using JavaScript? With JavaScript, the communication would be ActionScript to JavaScript, and JavaScript to server. There are many way to implement a direct communication between ActionScript and the server, considering there are XML-RPC clients for ActionScript, and Drupal implements a XML-RPC server by default, without any extra modules being installed.

Comment: As far as I know it must be Javascript, not ActionScript. I'll check all the answers, it may take me a while, thanks.

Comment: ActionScript is the scripting language used in Macromedia Flash.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it the JS part, Drupal part will be quite easy.

Create module with form that handle data transfer to Drupal and submit this form via Ajax https://drupal.org/node/752056

It can be helpful too: [Match JSON POST data with custom node fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31202/match-json-post-data-with-custom-node-fields)